Plotting scaled model predictors
You may want to scale a continuous variable before you use it as a model predictor. For example, using the mtcars dataset you can model mpg as a response to scaled hp, and create a plot for it.
library(ggplot2)

mtcars<-mtcars
summary(mtcars)

model1 <- lm(mpg ~ scale(hp),data=mtcars)
summary(model1)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ scale(hp), data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.7121 -2.1122 -0.8854  1.5819  8.2360 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  20.0906     0.6829  29.420  < 2e-16 ***
scale(hp)    -4.6779     0.6938  -6.742 1.79e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.863 on 30 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6024,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5892 
F-statistic: 45.46 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 1.788e-07

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x =scale(hp), y = mpg))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept= 20.0906,slope =-4.6779))+ 
  theme_classic()+ theme(
    text = element_text(size = 12)
  )


The plot also has scaled hp on the x axis, but what if you want to use the original unscaled variable for a plot? If you use the same slope and intersect, but with unscaled hp the slope will be so steep that it won't be visible (not shown here).
To remedy this, you could make a new plot using the same model but with new intercepts and slopes, gained by removing the initial hp scaling (see below). But my question is: should you? Is it fair to report on a model output and then use a different model in the associated figure, if they are functionally the same? Or is this bad practice?


It's absolutely OK, and in fact I would recommend it, since the plot will almost certainly be easier for your audience to interpret. You're not changing anything fundamental about the model fit, just the way you report it.
